# Why TKinter label is not defined?

Tags: python, tkinter

Today I just started to learn Tkinter (so basically, I don't know anything about it)
I'm using Hyper terminal, with Bash. I typed "python app.py" (app is my file name)
And it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\MyFolderName\Python\app.py", line 15, in
>
> testlabel = Label(root, NameError: name 'Label' is not defined

That's the error. Everything was imported successfully, I tested it. Bash also works well.
Maybe the source code is needed for the answer so there it is:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('800x600')


testlabel = Label(root,
    text= "Hello world!!").place(x = 40, y = 130)

testlabel.pack()
root.title('Test project...')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Basically the same error. `Label` belongs to `tkinter` namespace. you need `tk.Label` since you have imported `tkinter as tk`

Answer (score 0):

Label is not defined
use your import to get Label
`testlabel = tk.Label(root, text= "Hello world!!").place(x = 40, y = 130)`

and the same for all other items...

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved.